# Can someone explain this java code

Tags: java

This is a solution for a [topcoder SRM 569 DIV 2 problem 250](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=12404&rd=15489) by Zyflair

I can't understand the code or how it is working can someone explain it or simplify it.

```
public int countSupervisors(int[] students, int Y, int J){
  for(int i = 0,Y2 = Y + (Y = 0),J2=J+(J=0) ;i<students.length; i++,Y +=students [i -1 ] ){
   J =Math.max(J,-(Math.max(0, students[i]-Y2)+J2-1)/J2+(students[i] = (students[i]+J2-1)/J2));
        }
  return Y-J;
}
```

Comment: What a nasty piece of code. Competitors usually do that so their code is hard to understand (and, therefore, to challenge). What's the problem description? A little more context would help.

Comment: can you post the problem or link it?

Comment: I would not call the writer of that a "top coder".

Comment: The problem is here http://apps.topcoder.com/wiki/display/tc/SRM+569

Comment: No . Nobody could explain this code.

Comment: I've never seen one array access next to another like that.. interesting. This bit: `(students[i] (students[i]+J2-1)/J2-1)`

Comment: @ChrisDennett There was a mistake in the code, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really have time to study the problem now, but here's a bit of a simplification:

```
// Y2 = Y + (Y = 0)
int Y2 = Y;
Y = 0;

// J2 = J + (J = 0)
int J2 = J;
J = 0;

// Note that, since we've just set Y and J to 0,
//   we may as well have used different variables

for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++)
{
   int temp = (students[i] + J2 - 1) / J2;
   J = Math.max(J, -(Math.max(0, students[i] - Y2) + J2 - 1) / J2 + temp);
   Y += temp;
}
return Y-J;
```